# C++ using a static library within a project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, reference, static-libraries, unresolved-external

I have a static library project that I am trying to use in a Win32 form project. I am using visual studio and C++. Here is what I have done:

- Added the library project to the solution.
- Included the library project's header in stdafx.h of the form project (#include "..\libproj\libProj.lib")
- Linked the static library file itself using pragma (#pragma comment(lib,"..\libproj\Release\libProj.lib")
- Added a reference to the library project in "Common Properties > Framework and References".

But when I try and compile the form application I get numerous unresolved external symbol errors. I just don't know what I am doing wrong. Currently I am getting round this problem by adding the .cpp file of the library project to the windows forms project. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you show us the errors?

Comment: I actually can't right now - my office internet is down so I'm asking the question from my iPad. I can tell you the only output lines that show up as "error" are purely unresolved external symbol errors for every time a function inside the library is called.

Comment: Do you use the same Runtime Library for both projects? (Config. Properties>C/C++>Code Generation>Runtime Library)

Comment: "differing calling conventions in the client and the precompiled library usually result in an unresolved error during linking", from: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/static-library-tips-r1583

Comment: Yes the same runtime library is used.